# If I Have a Live USB with Persistence, if I install it, will the persistence be included

Tags: installation, usb, persistence

Let's say I want to take a live USB with persistence, boot into it, get it all setup then install it. Will all my features still be there?

If not, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will the data from my persistent Live-USB automatically transfer when I install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166093/will-the-data-from-my-persistent-live-usb-automatically-transfer-when-i-install)

Answer (score 2):

No. The UsB Persistence, does make changes and keeps them only for the Live instance. In some cases, further modification is required to enable things like graphical card settings and network card settings to be saved. In other cases, system wide updates do not work.

To make permanent changes to your Live USB you should use [RemastrerSys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remastersys)
For example you can :

- clean install Ubuntu, in a virtual machine (see [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox)),
- Install remastersys in it
- Make any changes you want
- Then make an new ISO file that contains all your changes