# Migrating Ubuntu 14.04 from persistent live USB to laptop

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, clone

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a persistent Live 8GB USB stick. It works fine, I've installed a lot of software and set up a PostgreSQL database as well as a few git repositories.

Is it possible to duplicate everything to a large partition on my laptop?

If I simply use Ubuntu Live to install Ubuntu on my laptop; it won't have everything I need - ready to go. And if I clone the disc image; I assume it will also clone the 4GB casper-rw file as it's storage rather than using the larger partition.

So yeah, my question is: Is it possible to duplicate everything on my Ubuntu Live USB to a large partition on my laptop?

Comment: Actually; I believe this may be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/166093/will-the-data-from-my-persistent-live-usb-automatically-transfer-when-i-install

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried command called "dd". You need to use it from terminal, but its kinda bit by bit copy software.

After succesfully transfered data from usb to HDD reboot and use gparted to maximaze your partition to full HDD size.

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/dd.htm

Comment: But my Live USB is using a casper-rw file to store persistent data. Not a partition.