# Ubuntu Live CD - Persistance and install

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, persistence

If I were to use a Ubuntu live USB with persistence for a while, and then when I am comfortable with it, choose to install it to a Hard Disk, will my persistent data transfer over? Or will I get a vanilla Ubuntu install, as per the read only part of the Live USB?

There is an exact duplicate(one that I could find) in [If I Have a Live USB with Persistence, if I install it, will the persistence be included](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110948/if-i-have-a-live-usb-with-persistence-if-i-install-it-will-the-persistence-be), however the one answer there seems to be rather confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ubuntu **live USB with persistence** can be used to install Ubuntu on hard disk but it simply produces a **fresh install** with no transfer of any system-wide or user settings, data, etc.
2. It is possible to transfer most **user settings** and data from your **home folder** (e.g. sub-folders like **.mozilla**, **.thunderbird**, etc.) by simply copying and pasting them to your new home folder, and same applies to **data files** in folders like Documents, Pictures, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. #2 is fine but doesn't work for some cases like a) installed app list, b) the hardest, but rarest - changes to root configuration (/etc/*)

Comment: For (a) you can a look at the article "2 WAYS OF REINSTALLING ALL OF YOUR CURRENT INSTALLED PACKAGES ON A FRESH UBUNTU INSTALLATION" at: www.webupd8.org/2010/03/2-ways-of-reinstalling-all-of-your.html

Answer (score 0):

No, installing Ubuntu is like installing a fresh copy of Windows or Mac OS X(Ten). So any persistence you have set up as the LiveUSB will be lost.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a repeat of the other answer..

Comment: No problem, happy to help.